# Cannot pass arguments to push action in bash script

Tags: cleos, action, bash, json

I am using a bash script to push actions. 
Here is the script :

```
echo "------------------> Pushing action $1"
#cleos -u https://api-kylin.eoslaomao.com:443 push action user1account issue '["user1account","2 STR",["first","second"],"first_token","firstmemo"]' -p user1account@active
echo "------------------> Arguments"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
if [[ "$1" == "create" ]]; then
    cleos -u https://api-kylin.eoslaomao.com:443 push action user1account create '["$2","$3"]' -p user1account@active
elif [[ "$1" == "issue" ]]; then
    cleos -u https://api-kylin.eoslaomao.com:443 push action user1account issue '["$2","$3",["$4","$5"],"$6","$7"]' -p user1account@active
elif [[ "$1" == "transferid" ]]; then
    cleos -u https://api-kylin.eoslaomao.com:443 push action user1account transferid '["$2","$3","$4","$5"]' -p user1account@active
    #statements
elif [[ "$1" == "transfer" ]]; then
    cleos -u https://api-kylin.eoslaomao.com:443 push action user1account transfer '["$2","$3","$4","$5"]' -p user1account@active
elif [[ "$1" == "mint" ]]; then
    cleos -u https://api-kylin.eoslaomao.com:443 push action user1account mint '["$2","$3","$4","$5","$6"]' -p user1account@active
else
    echo "No action has been pushed or the action given hasn't been added in the script"

fi
```

I am running the following in terminal :

```
./push.sh create user1account STE
```

I get the following error:

```
Error 3010001: Invalid name
Name should be less than 13 characters and only contains the following symbol .12345abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Error Details:
Name not properly normalized (name: $2, normalized: .2)
```

Comment: When I run `cleos -u https://api-kylin.eoslaomao.com:443 push action user1account create '["user1account","STE"]' -p user1account@active` , the transaction is successfully executed.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use single quotes to allow these arguments that are within json. Like this:

```
cleos -u https://api-kylin.eoslaomao.com:443 push action user1account create '["'$2'","'$3'"]' -p user1account@active
```